# ios, Documents folder empty on device but not on simulator?

Tags: ios, plist

When I NSLog my Documents dir on my Simulator I see the files

```
2013-01-02 17:02:02.398 ForPlayAtl[2113:1a903] docs check (
"biz.plist",
"sched.plist",
"ver.plist",


)
2013-01-02 17:02:02.400 ForPlayAtl[2113:1a903] docs path check /Users/Dude/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/
```

When I do the same on my device I get

```
2013-01-02 16:56:01.896 ForPlayAtl[2253:907] docs check (
)
2013-01-02 16:56:01.900 ForPlayAtl[2253:907] docs path check /var/mobile/Applications/A7B36683-C41B-4DF5-A9C3-1FDF0F0DCBDD/Documents
```

my function looks like this

```
-(NSString *) dataFilePath
{
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];

    return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sched.plist"];

    }
```

case sensitivity has been checked. My working assumption is .plists get copied to device from the /Documents dir ? No ?   do I need to maybe init a .plist first ?

What am I missing ...thanks for the help. very appreciated

Comment: You're lucky you're getting anything at all, because your NSLog() should never actually execute in the code your provided.

Comment: Nothing gets copied unless you specify it to be copied.